# How to figure out elapsed time in days, hours and minutes with bash? (and print it nicely)

Tags: terminal

I want to find out how many days, hours and minutes have passed since a certain time using the shell (`bash`). `awk` seems like the right tool, because I need to calculate, format and print to the command line.

Expected Output:

```
"Elapsed Time: "
"Days:  3123"
"Hours:  12"
"Minutes: 23"
```

Algorithm idea:

```
time_now = get_time()
time_then = some_constant

diff = time_now - time_then     # this is all in seconds
days = round(  diff / 86400  )      # to nearest floor integer
print( days )    

diff -= diff - (days*86400)
hours = round(  diff/3600 )
print (hours)

diff = diff - (hours*3600)
minutes = round(  diff/60  )
print( minutes )
```

How can I do this in `awk`? I came up with this:

```
date +%s | awk '{time_then = 815002800; diff = $1-time_then}; {print (diff/86400)}' | sed 's/\.[1-9]*//' | awk '{print "Days:  " $0 }'
```

The sed removes numbers after the decimal. Always rounds the number down (so its an integer).

So how can I jam the hours and minutes in there? It feels like there must be a better way. Maybe I am using the wrong tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You algorithm can be directly expressed in awk:

```
date +%s | awk '{
time_now = 815002800
time_then = some_constant

diff = time_now - time_then     # this is all in seconds
days = int(diff / 86400)        # to nearest floor integer
print days 

diff -= days * 86400
hours = int(diff/3600)
print hours

diff -= hours*3600
minutes = int(diff/60)
print minutes 
}'
```

```

will print

```
9432
21
40
```

Comment: wow! awk is much more flexible than I thought. But do you think there is a way to do this in a simpler manner?

Comment: You could precompute some constants, use modulo arithmetic, or a loop.  Look at the source code of strftime.